# Google Chrome using way too much CPU

Tags: macos, google-chrome, browser

Over the last couple of weeks, every time I open Chrome on my laptop, it starts using 160-170% of the CPU (multiple cores). It gets really hot, the fan starts going crazy, and it runs the battery dead really fast. I've checked the Chrome task manager to see if any extension is bogging it down, but none is. I know this isn't directly code related but I didn't know where else to ask. I'm on a Macbook Pro by the way.

Comment: does it happen in an incognito session?

Comment: @HelpingHand Yes, it happens anytime the Chrome app is open